# How to configure dependencies on custom validator with Symfony Components?

Tags: php, validation, dependency-injection, symfony

I am using **Symfony Validator** and **Symfony Service Container** in a project, but not the full Symfony Framework.

I have written a custom validator that requires some dependencies to be supplied as constructor arguments.

The [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies) describes a method of configuring the validator as service, which I have done successfully. But then it makes of point of using the `validator.constraint_validator` **service tag**, which I suspect glues them together.

This service tag seems to be specific to when using the full Symfony Framework -- Symfony Validator is not magically loading my custom validator when I add this tag (unsurprisingly.)

So, how can I link the Validator and Service Container components? Or is there any other strategy for having Symfony Validator to load my customer validator with dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this tag (`validator.constraint_validator`) processed by compiler-pass from `Symfony/FrameworkBundle`. 
If you don't want to use this bundle, but you want to link DI container with validator, you should re-implement this process.

First, we need an instance of ConstraintValidatorFactoryInterface. [Default implementation](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintValidatorFactory.html) just looks for a class, with name returned by validatedBy() method of constraint. [Implementation from FrameworkBundle](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Validator/ConstraintValidatorFactory.html) considers result of validatedBy() as service identifier/or tag alias and gets this service from container. Our implementation should do something like that:

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidatorFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class ContainerConstraintValidatorFactory implements ConstraintValidatorFactoryInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getInstance(Constraint $constraint)
    {
        // Simplified implementation, just for example:
        return $this->container->get($constraint->validatedBy());
    }
}
```

For example, suppose we have some custom validation constraint and validator class with some dependency:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class CustomConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Oops!';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'validator.custom';
    }
}

class CustomConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $dependency;

    public function __construct($dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (rand() % 2 === 0) {
            $this->context
                ->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Next we register constraint validator as service with ID same as result of `validatedBy()` method from related constraint object. We create instance of the validator service related with container through this factory. All constraints validators, registered as same manner will be available.

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container->register(
    'validator.custom', 
    new CustomConstraintValidator('Some dependency value')
);

$validatorBuilder = Validation::createValidatorBuilder();
$validatorBuilder->setConstraintValidatorFactory(
    new ContainerConstraintValidatorFactory($container)
);
$validator = $validatorBuilder->getValidator();

$violations = $validator->validate('test value', [ 
    new CustomConstraint() 
]);
```

It works, however I recommend to consider of using `FrameworkBundle` to not reinvent the wheel. You can configure it to use only things that you need.

Comment: With your approach is it possible to use this custom constraint directly in form builder like below? `    ->add('email', EmailType::class, [                                              'constraints' => [
                              new CustomConstraint()
    ]])`  @Timurib

Comment: Your code is not working for me. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417417/how-to-pass-an-instance-to-symfony-form-validator-class and help. @Timurib