# How to pass an instance to symfony form validator class?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am trying to create a custom symfony form validator constraint. I created two class, one constraint and one validator and it works fine. But I need to pass doctrine entitymanager instance to validator class, as I am using them standalone and not framework, I don't have yaml configuration file. I created a constructor in validator class to have $em, and in controller I have:

```
->add('email', EmailType::class, [                                              
    'constraints' => [
        new Assert\Email(['message' => 'invalid.email', 'mode' => 'strict', 'normalizer' => 'trim']),
        new Assert\EmailExists($em),
    ],
 ]);
```

But I am not getting $em, in my validator class, what should I do? I also tried to have constructor in main constraint class, then in validator I had `parent::construct()`, still not working.

I did read this too [How to configure dependencies on custom validator with Symfony Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601866/how-to-configure-dependencies-on-custom-validator-with-symfony-components) but instead of making the factory class, I used the current factor class and used this:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ContainerConstraintValidatorFactory;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container
    ->register('customEmailUniqueEntity', 'EmailExistsValidator')
    ->addArgument($em);
$validatorBuilder = Validation::createValidatorBuilder();
$validatorBuilder->setConstraintValidatorFactory(
    new ContainerConstraintValidatorFactory($container)
);

$validator = $validatorBuilder->getValidator();
$violations = $validator->validate('email address', [ 
    new EmailExists() 
]);

if (0 !== count($violations)) {
    // there are errors, now you can show them
    foreach ($violations as $violation) {
        echo $violation->getMessage().'<br>';
    }
}
```

With this code both dependency injection and validation works fine, but is there a trick to have this custom constraint as 'constraint' array argument within form builder rather than validating it manually?

```
->add('email', EmailType::class, [                                              
    'constraints' => [
        new Assert\Email(['message' => 'invalid.email', 'mode' => 'strict', 'normalizer' => 'trim']),
        new Assert\EmailExists($em),
    ],
 ]);
```

With code above I cannot pass $em to the constructor of my custom Validator. Any trick possible?

EDIT:

In order to inject doctrine EntityManager, in `EmailExists` class I had:

```
 public function validatedBy()
 {
        return 'customEmailUniqueEntity';
        //return \get_class($this).'Validator';
 }
```

then I had:

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container
    ->register('customEmailUniqueEntity', 'EmailExistsValidator')
    ->addArgument($em);
```

because if I was returning validator class from `validatedBy()` I could not inject $em to the constructor of validator. With the answer below I used:

```
->addTag('validator.constraint_validator');
```

But now I am getting `customEmailUniqueEntity` class not found error, as if I return validator from `validatedBy()`, injection will not work, what should I do? I tried to return

```
 public function validatedBy()
 {
        return 'EmailExists';
        //return \get_class($this).'Validator';
 }
```

but this one, of course I am getting `initialize()` error. Please advise.

EDIT2:

I added addTag to:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ContainerConstraintValidatorFactory;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container
    ->register('customEmailUniqueEntity', 'EmailExistsValidator')
    ->addArgument($em),
    ->addTag('validator.constraint_validator');

$validatorBuilder = Validation::createValidatorBuilder();
$validatorBuilder->setConstraintValidatorFactory(
    new ContainerConstraintValidatorFactory($container)
);

$validator = $validatorBuilder->getValidator();
$violations = $validator->validate('email address', [ 
    new EmailExists() 
]);

if (0 !== count($violations)) {
    // there are errors, now you can show them
    foreach ($violations as $violation) {
        echo $violation->getMessage().'<br>';
    }
}
```

and in constructor of EmailExistsValidator I have:

```
var_dump($em);
```

and I got $em object in validator, so $em is injected and adding `addTag()` did not cause any error. If I remove `validatedBy()` of `EmailExists` contsraint, injection will not be done. In that method I am doing

```
return `customEmailUniqueEntity;`
```

because if I return `EmailExistsValidator`, injection will not be done.
Now how to use `validator.constraint_validator` or `EmailExists()` as constraints array param of the form? if I use `new EmailExists()` I will get Two Few Aguments for validator class as $em wll not be injected this way. What to do?

Comment: You have symfony4 - typehint an argument for constructor, either of form or of validator.

Comment: just constructor of `EmailExists` constraint, but I know it should be in validator, but how to pass it to validator?

Answer (score 1):

Constraints are not validators.
Symfony will take a constraint and search for its validator by attaching `Validator` to the classname.
So in symfony you register your constraint by `EmailExists` but the class/service which actually does validation is `EmailExistsValidator`.
And this is also the place to inject `EntityManagerInterface` into it.

All information can be found here: [Symfony - How to Create a custom Validation Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Comment: I had read the link you gave before posting here, and I know I have to have EntityManager instance in `EmailExistsValidator`. I asked how? I added a constructor to that class but the instance still not available.

Answer (score 1):

Your `customEmailUniqueEntity` service will never be taken into account by the `ContainerConstraintValidatorFactory` when it determines the actual validator to be used for the `EmailExists` constraint.

In order to let the factory know which services are constraint validators you need to tag it with the `validator.constraint_validator` tag like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\DependencyInjection\AddConstraintValidatorsPass;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container
    ->register('customEmailUniqueEntity', 'EmailExistsValidator')
    ->addArgument($em)
    ->addTag('validator.constraint_validator');
$container->addCompilerPass(new AddConstraintValidatorPass());
$container->compile();
```

Comment: Please read 'EDIT' area in main post. This is not yet working, please advise. @xabbuh

Comment: Please remove the `validatedBy()` method from your constraint. It's not needed.

Comment: By removing `validatedBy`, this time I get `Too few arguments to function EmailExistsValidator::__construct(), 0 passed` and injection is not working, but I still had `->addArgument($em)`. Please advise. @xabbuh

Comment: I guess in `add()` of form I should not use `EmailExists()` but something else due to `customEmailUniqueEntity` as first param of `register()`? @xabbuh

Comment: In `EDIT2` I tried to clarify what exactly I did, please read that part and advise. @xabbuh

Comment: I missed that you didn't compile your container. You need to register the `AddConstraintValidatorPass` which is responsible to handle the `validator.constraint_validator` tag when the container is compiled. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I guess the same way I can get built-in UniqueEntity worked and avoid "doctrine.orm.validator' classs not found error. Possible? How to use UniqueEntity constraint outside of framework? @xabbuh

Comment: You need to register the `UniqueEntityValidator` as a service in a similar manner.